# Why is this Haskell incorrect?

Tags: syntax, haskell, syntax-error

I have a Haskell file which looks like this:

```
longest::[Integer]->[Integer]->[Integer]
max a b = if length a > length b then a else b

llfs::[Integer]->Integer
llfs li = length(foldl longest group(li))

llfs([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1])
```

Which should print out the result of the function call at the end, however when I run the file I get this error:

```
parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. What should I do to fix it?

---

**Edit**

After putting the last line inside the main function, like this:

```
import List

longest::[Integer]->[Integer]->[Integer]
longest a b = if length a > length b then a else b

llfs::[Integer]->Integer
llfs li = length(foldl longest group(li))

main = print (llfs [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1])
```

I now get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Haskell\Q1.hs:7:31:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Integer]'
           against inferred type `[a] -> [[a]]'
    In the second argument of `foldl', namely `group'
    In the first argument of `length', namely
        `(foldl longest group (li))'
    In the expression: length (foldl longest group (li))
```

This one looks a little more difficult! How do I solve it?

Comment: Is there more to this file? Maybe a main function?

Comment: No, that's it, as I understood it Haskell just ran function calls as it came across them in the file (like python, for example)

Comment: Editing the question to reflect a new error I get ><

Comment: By the way, for your llfs function you might want to check out Data.List.maximumBy and then Data.Function.on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
module Main where

import Data.List

longest::[Integer]->[Integer]->[Integer]
longest a b = if length a > length b then a else b

llfs::[Integer]->Int
llfs li = length $ foldl1 longest $ group li

main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ llfs [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: "llfs li = length $ foldl1 longest $ group li" 
Is the same as 
"llfs li = length (foldl1 longest ( group li))

Comment: @Martin: then find a good tutorial and get familiar with the $ operator.  It's very, very useful ;-)  @Caleb: you don't need 'do' for only one statement.

Comment: Well using foldl1 instead of foldl fixed the problem!

Comment: Damn, I understand why, I misread the documentation for foldl and foldl1

Answer (score 7):

Your code isn't correct.

This

```
longest::[Integer]->[Integer]->[Integer]
max a b = if length a > length b then a else b
```

should be

```
longest::[Integer]->[Integer]->[Integer]
longest a b = if length a > length b then a else b
```

And you need a main function

```
main = do print llfs([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1])
```

Just for the sake of improving your code, if you have a function signature and give it a lower case letter(s) as its type (say the letter a), it becomes generic. For example

```
longest:: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
longest x y = if length x > length y then x else y
```

Means that rather than just working on lists of Integers, it works on lists of anything. Suddenly you have a very reusable function.

Answer (score 7):

In the line

```
llfs li = length(foldl longest group(li))
```

the interpreter is treating `group` as the second argument to `foldl`.  Writing `group(li)` is no different from writing `group li`.

Also, `foldl` needs an initial value.  `foldl1`, on the other hand, uses the first list element for its initial value.  Try:

```
llfs li = length (foldl1 longest (group li))
```

(Edited to remove the first, wrong answer.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem was that the last line did not define a function, as others have stated. More things are wrong in your code. It appears this is what you want to do:

```
import Data.List

longest_group_size :: [Integer] -> Int
longest_group_size = maximum . map length . group

main :: IO ()
main = print $ longest_group_size [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1]
```

Observe that:

1. You need to `import` [`Data.List`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html) in order to use [`group`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3Agroup).
2. No need to use [`foldr`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Afoldr) in this case: by using [`map`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Amap) the length of each group is only calculated once.
3. This does mean, of course, that we call in the help of another function, [`maximum`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Amaximum).

Comment: Ok, so that's a better solution. I would still like to understand this new error I'm getting though

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call a function at file scope like you would do in python or other scripting languages. Therefore the "call" to `llfs` in the last line is an error. Try printing the result in `main`:

```
main = print (llfs [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1])
```

At the moment the "function call" looks like an incomplete function definition, where the right side is missing, which leads to the surprising error message:

```
llfs (...) = abc
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
llfs([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1])
```

That's not a function declaration. I think you're trying to make a function call, in which case you need to put it inside a `main` declaration. You can also load the Haskell file into an interpreter (e.g., `ghci`) and execute the function call in the interpreter console.

Comment: +1 for poiting out more clearly what caused the error, not just the correction

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the direct cause of either error, but I think it's a contributing factor to your misunderstanding. In Haskell, you would never write `group(li)`. Parenthesizing a single argument is pointless — it's exactly equivalent to `group li`. If you're trying to pass the result of this function call to another function, you need to parenthesize the whole expression — `(group li)` — or use the `$` operator like Caleb suggested.

Comment: @Martin: It will be harder for most Haskell programmers. I think you're just not used to Haskell syntax yet.

Answer (score 2):

Two small issues with the update. First, it looks like you're trying to pass the `group` result as an argument to `foldl`. The right way to say that is `(group li)` rather than `group(li)` The second is that `foldl` needs a base case. Caleb's suggestion to use `foldl1` is one option that will probably work for you.